# How to get sum of two variables which are inside two different function inside two input events and both are in local scope?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the sum of the two input field's values, but I have no idea how to do it. both are inside event listener's function which made each of them in local scope so that I cannot access those calculated values outside those functions.
I need to get the sum of variables "totalNormal" and "totalOver"

I want to do it with pure javascript if possible.
I don't want to use any button with onclick.
is there any way to do it.

This is the code:

```js
 document.getElementById("normalOutput").style.visibility="hidden";
 document.getElementById("overOutput").style.visibility="hidden";
 document.getElementById("totalOutput").style.visibility="hidden";
  

 //event input regular
 document.getElementById("getNtInput").addEventListener("input", function(e){
  document.getElementById("normalOutput").style.visibility="visible";
  let normal= e.target.value;
  let totalNormal=normal*900;
  document.getElementById("normaltimeOutput").innerHTML= totalNormal + " JPY";
  
 
 }, false);
 let totalOver
 document.getElementById("getOtInput").addEventListener("input", function(d){
  document.getElementById("overOutput").style.visibility="visible";
  document.getElementById("totalOutput").style.visibility="visible";
  let over= d.target.value;
  totalOver = over*1125;
  document.getElementById("overtimeOutput").innerHTML= totalOver + " JPY";

 }, false);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 100px;
      }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-center mb-3">Wage Calculator</h1>
    <form action="">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input id="getNtInput" type="number" name="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter Normal Hours">
      <input id="getOtInput" type="number" name="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter Overtime Hours">
     </div>
    </form>
    <div id="output">
     <div id="normalOutput" class="card bg-danger mb-3 ">
      <div class="card-block">
       <h1>Earned From Normal Hour:</h1>
       <h3 id="normaltimeOutput"></h3>

      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="overOutput" class="card bg-primary mb-3">
      <div class="card-block">
       <h1>Earned from Overtime:</h1>
       <div id="overtimeOutput"></div>

      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="totalOutput" class="card bg-success mb-3">
      <div class="card-block">
       <h1>Total Earned Today:</h1>
       <div id="totalOutput"></div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The output till now looks like this ;
http://neeshann.but.jp/wageCalculator.html

Comment: *I don't want to use any button with onclick.* <-- Then when do you want to get the result?

Comment: @ScottMarcus When the input changes, I think. You should just store the input dom element globally and address them in the handlers instead of using `event.target`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You acknowledge that you've got local variables in two different functions and want to use them outside of the functions. So, declare them at a higher scope that is common to both functions - problem solved.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c0f1243b/ Try this Nishan

Comment: when user inputs numbers, the value in Earned From Normal Hour: and Earned from Overtime: are generated simultaneously and I want the Total Earned Today: to be updated after both input field gets input, maybe using if statement, I tried a lot for hours nothing works, I am a beginner to js. Thank you Marcus

Answer (score 0):

Illustrated here:
https://jsfiddle.net/c0f1243b/

Just make the output of both of those input functions a closure variable so that other external functions can access its value.

```
let totalNormal;
document.getElementById("getNtInput").addEventListener("input", function(e){
    document.getElementById("normalOutput").style.visibility="visible";
    let normal= e.target.value;
    totalNormal=normal*900;
    document.getElementById("normaltimeOutput").innerHTML= totalNormal + " JPY";

    renderTotal();
}, false);

let totalOver;
document.getElementById("getOtInput").addEventListener("input", function(d){
    document.getElementById("overOutput").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("totalOutput").style.visibility="visible";
    let over= d.target.value;
    totalOver = over*1125;
    document.getElementById("overtimeOutput").innerHTML= totalOver + " JPY";

    renderTotal();
}, false);

function renderTotal() {
    // potentially check if both values are set
    const t = totalOver + totalNormal;
    document.getElementById("totalOutputDiv").innerHTML= t + " JPY";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much TKoL

Comment: No problem @NishanThapa. remember to mark the answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

I just computed the total whenever the user type numbers and update the total when both inputs are not empty.

```js
document.getElementById("normalOutput").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("overOutput").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("totalOutput").style.visibility = "hidden";

let firstInput = document.getElementById("getNtInput");
let secondInput = document.getElementById("getOtInput");

function calc_and_show() {
  let v1 = firstInput.value;
  let v2 = secondInput.value;
  if (v1 !== '' && v2 !== '') {
    document.getElementById("totalOutput").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("totalOutputv").innerHTML = v1 * 900 + v2 * 1125;
  }
}
//event input regular
document.getElementById("getNtInput").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  document.getElementById("normalOutput").style.visibility = "visible";
  let normal = e.target.value;
  let totalNormal = normal * 900;
  document.getElementById("normaltimeOutput").innerHTML = totalNormal + " JPY";
  calc_and_show();


}, false);
let totalOver
document.getElementById("getOtInput").addEventListener("input", function(d) {
  document.getElementById("overOutput").style.visibility = "visible";
  let over = d.target.value;
  totalOver = over * 1125;
  document.getElementById("overtimeOutput").innerHTML = totalOver + " JPY";
  calc_and_show();
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h1 class="display-3 text-center mb-3">Wage Calculator</h1>
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="getNtInput" type="number" name="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter Normal Hours">
            <input id="getOtInput" type="number" name="" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter Overtime Hours">
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="output">
          <div id="normalOutput" class="card bg-danger mb-3 ">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h1>Earned From Normal Hour:</h1>
              <h3 id="normaltimeOutput"></h3>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="overOutput" class="card bg-primary mb-3">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h1>Earned from Overtime:</h1>
              <div id="overtimeOutput"></div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="totalOutput" class="card bg-success mb-3">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h1>Total Earned Today:</h1>
              <div id="totalOutputv"></div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code a bit, to make it easier to see what is going on. The trick is that you store all yours inputs and outputs in global scope. I even placed them inside objects here to make your code easy to read. Then all you need to do is *one* update function instead of multiple, and then just update everything in there. Register this update for every input that changes and your system works together like this:

```js
const outputs = {
  normal: document.getElementById("normaltimeOutput"),
  over: document.getElementById("overtimeOutput"),
  total: document.getElementById("totalOutput")
};
const inputs = {
  normal: document.getElementById("normaltimeInput"),
  over: document.getElementById("overtimeInput")
};

function update(){

  outputs.normal.innerHTML = inputs.normal.value * 900;
  outputs.over.innerHTML = inputs.over.value * 1125;
  outputs.total.innerHTML = inputs.normal.value * 1125 + inputs.over.value * 1125;
  
}

for( let input in inputs ){
  
  inputs[input].addEventListener( 'input', update );
  
}
```

```css
h1, h3 { font-size: 1rem; }
```

```html
<input id="normaltimeInput" type="number" value="0" placeholder="Enter Normal Hours" />
<input id="overtimeInput" type="number" value="0" placeholder="Enter Overtime Hours" />

<h1>Earned From Normal Hours:</h1>
<h3 id="normaltimeOutput">0</h3>
<h1>Earned from Overtime:</h1>
<h3 id="overtimeOutput">0</h3>
<h1>Total Earned Today:</h1>
<h3 id="totalOutput">0</h3>
```

I think this keeps things rather clear, and your actual calculation is limited to *one* place, so if you have to make changes later your know where to look.